# ¿Cómo transferir una contraseña de forma segura del cliente al servidor?

Tags: php, javascript, encriptación

Quiero saber cómo enviar una contraseña de manera segura al servidor. Se me ocurre que podría encriptarla con javascript (usando una función hash de alguna librería) y desencriptarla con php -para hacer la validación del lado del servidor, y si es posible, claro-.
Espero y puedan ayudarme. Gracias

Comment: con certificados ssl

Comment: Creo que exponer tus algoritmos o formas de encriptación del lado del cliente es un poco riesgoso, considero que lo mejor es encriptar del lado del servidor la contraseña que recibas (literal) desde el formulario. Otra opcion es que puedes utilizar dos formas de encriptar, una para que viaje del cliente al servidor y en el servidor utilizas otro tipo de encriptación para que asi quien logre interceptar la peticion despues de que sale del navegador no sea capaz de detectar el valor que realmente esta en la BD

Comment: Complementando un poco lo que dijo @MichaelOspina, concuerdo conque nunca debes mostrar tu método de encriptación. Además de eso mencionas que quieres desencriptarla, lo cual es una idea aún peor, nunca deberías guardar contraseñas desencriptadas en tu BDD, por lo que deberías guardarlas encriptarlas, obtener la contraseña del usuario, encriptarla y comparar que ambas cadenas encriptadas sean iguales.

Comment: @Killbunny Ah, ¿entonces a siempre que se encriptan datos con el mismo algoritmo se obtienen los mismos resultados?¿Se pueden comparar sin la necesidad de desencriptar?

Comment: Exacto, lo importante es que a la BD llegue el valor encriptado. Ahora si quieres encriptar desde el cliente hazlo asi: encriptas en javascript, recibes en php el valor y ese valor lo desencriptas en la misma forma del javascript y lo encriptas en php de otra forma que ya no sea publica y el valor resultante se va a la bd

Comment: quizas, tambien podria utilizar un metodo de encriptacion en javascript y lo que llegue lo encriptas en php con  otro metodo y asi se guardara en la DB y cuando lo necesites compara siempre lo pasas por los dos filtros :)

Answer (score 1):

No importa mucho que expongas el método de cifrado siempre y cuando sea relativamente seguro y en la implementación no expongas llaves, salt o vectores de iniciación, SHA-256 por ejemplo, se considera "[incosteable](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1145/how-much-would-it-cost-in-u-s-dollars-to-brute-force-a-256-bit-key-in-a-year/1160#1160)" crackear.

Sin embargo, si se trata de passwords, mi sugerencia sería usar hashes en lugar de cifrados. Toma **[bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)** por ejemplo, no tiene problema implementar en el cliente una librería que genere el hash y lo envíe al servidor, de cualquier forma el atacante no sabría que llaves, salt o IV's se usaron para iniciar Blowfish si estos se renuevan en cada intento.

Ya en PHP puedes comparar el string que recibiste VS el hash que tengas en la base de datos, **no serán iguales** pero puedes usar [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php) para la comparación.